# How to get percentage in float 0 to 1 with integer values?

Tags: java

I need to get a float value based on percentage.

*For example*:

`1%: 0.01
10%: 0.10
25%: 0.25
50%: 0.5`

And so on.

I've tried getting a 0-100 percent value(Which works) and uploading it to a string:

`String value = "0." + percent;`

and parsing it as a float:

`Float.parseFloat(value);`

But that doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to display a number between 0 and 1 in binary?

Comment: `if (s == "0.100")` - Compare `String`s with `.equals`.

Comment: 5 out of 10, therfore 50% should be 0.1?

Comment: are you looking for `(x - min) / (max - min)`?

Comment: Absolutely no idea what you want to achieve. What do you mean with "0-1 percentage"? And why is 5 out of 10 0.1?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float percentage = (float)intPersentValue/100.0f;
this will give floating value like 25 to 0.25

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually get the question but are you trying to get

```
0.1 => 1.0 
0.015 => 0.1
```

or

```
0.1  => 100% 
0.01 => 10%
```

If you want 5/10 => 0.5 you can use:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
float percentage = (float)a/float(b);
```

If you can elaborate a bit more I can help.

Comment: Well the idea is to set the progress of a View that requires a float 0-1 to the percentage of a cap and number. Basically getting a percentage of 0 to 100 and turning it to a float 0-1

Comment: so you need to use @blackbelt 's answer. `(float) i/ (float)iCap` If we set min = 0.0.

Comment: We removed the min because min is 0.0 already in (x - min) / (max - min). We just added a typecast to float. Without typecase: 10/100 = 0

Comment: so x/max? Maximum is one so it would stay the same.

Comment: Maximum is 100 in you case.

Comment: but no, I need it to be 0-1. I fixed it though, I'll edit what i did in a little later.